# getting New and Reconditioned price using php in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, php-5.4

[image]

Hello everyone! So I have been tasked with creating a php function for the details listed above, I know that I want to do this in the view.phtml file, yet I'm a little unsure as how to start the If, else statements for the function and how to display the New product price, the reconditioned price and as well as the repair message, please help!